# Nivel de acesso e hierarquia ao marcar uns checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Fala galera, beleza? Podem me ajudar com uma coisa? Vou explicar:

Entro com o usuário admin e ele mostra todas as permissões do sistema. Como exemplo, suponhamos que tenha 10 (index, show, create, update, delete de usuario e perfil). Dessas 10 eu marco 4, salvo e crio um novo usuário. Ao me logar com esse novo usuário, eu quero apenas que mostre os 4 checkboxes que marquei e não os 10 como eram mostrados anteriormente. E assim por diante. Em resumo, cada novo usuário só pode marcar quantidade igual ou inferior aos checkboxes marcados pelo usuário que o criou.

Esse é meu codigo no form:

```
<% Role.to_a.in_groups_of(2, false) do |group| %>
  <div>
    <%- group.each do |role, label| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <%- f.object.permissions.to_a.group_by(&:role).each do |role_name, permissions| %>
          <% next if "#{role}" != "#{role_name}" -%>
          <br /><br />
          <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <h4><%= role[:label] %></h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row form-group">
  <%- role[:actions].each do |action| %>
    <%- permissions.each do |permission| %>
      <%- next if permission.action != "#{action}" %>
      <%= f.fields_for :permissions, permission do |fp| %>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= fp.hidden_field :id if f.object.persisted? %>
          <%= fp.hidden_field :role %>
          <%= fp.hidden_field :action %>
          <%= fp.label :permit, class: "label-checkbox inline" do %>
            <%= fp.check_box :permit %>
            <%= Role.action(role[:role], action)[:label] %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <br/>
  <br />
  <hr/>
</div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Com esse codigo consigo mostrar sempre todos as permissões, independente do usuário. Como resolver isso? ANTIGAMENTE, eu tinha feito dessa maneira e deu certo:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px">
  <div style="float: left;" class="input-group">
    <% if current_usuario.admin? %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :funcionalidade_ids, Funcionalidade.all, :id, :descricao %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :funcionalidade_ids, current_usuario.perfil.funcionalidades, :id, :descricao %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Porém como mudou bastante o sistema, da forma que está atualmente não consigo mais fazer da maneira anterior :(
Me deem uma força ai, por favor! Abraço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cria um escopo que relacione as permissões ao tipo de usuário (`role`), assim você pode pegar as permissões referentes ao usuário logado.

Na view você faria algo como:

`role.permissions.each`